# Kamailio install

Tags: mysql, kamailio

First I would like to say I am new in this.
I am trying to install Kamailio on Ubuntu Linux Mint and I have this problem.

It says i dont have that directory.. how can i create it ?
i was following this steps.
https://www.kamailio.org/wiki/install/4.4.x/git

> In file included from km_val.c:30:0:
>   km_val.h:32:19: fatal error: mysql.h: Adresár alebo súbor neexistuje
>   compilation terminated.
>   ../../Makefile.rules:97: recipe for target 'km_val.o' failed
>   make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsCGS.png): *** [km_val.o] Error 1
>   Makefile:511: recipe for target 'modules' failed
>   make: *** [modules] Error 1

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install **libmysqlclient-dev** package:

```
apt install libmysqlclient-dev
```

On latest Debian-based operating systems that ship either with MySQL or MariaDB, you may have to install **default-libmysqlclient-dev**:

```
apt install default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

It is also recommended to install **pkg-config** package in order to discover the extra dependencies brought in by the specific mysql client library.